# How to switch to full screen one of tabs on conemu splited screen

Tags: conemu

I have a 2x2 ConEmu screen. How can I go full screen with one of my tabs for better log reading, and switch back to the splited mode?

It is realy handy feature but I could not find out if it is available in ConEmu!

I'm running ConEmu151210[64] on windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried to open Settings? https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsHotkeys.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [Default hotkey](https://conemu.github.io/en/KeyboardShortcuts.html)

Easy to find. <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, `pane`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Now it is by default `Win+Ctrl+Alt+Enter`.

Comment: how do i get out of it ?

Answer (score 0):

For ConEmu-Maximus5 version 180626 running on windows 7, I customized the shortcut:

**Settings** > **Keys & Macro**:
Scroll to the option:
**Split: Maximize/restore active pane: Split(3)**

Choose hotkey: `Enter`, `Win`

I selected `Win` since my laptop keyboard does not have the [Apps key](https://conemu.github.io/en/AppsKey.html).

With this setting, I can toggle between pane and full window mode by typing `Win+Enter`